# decision on jQuery ajax json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Following the my jQuery ajasx request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '$url_validateserial',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.isOK);
        console.log(result.message);
        if (result.isOk == false) {
            alert(result.message);
        } else {
            serialvalidated = true;
            $('#iid').val(result.inventoryitem_id);
            $('#serial').attr('readonly', true);
            $('#carrierid').attr('readonly', false);
        }
    },
    async:   false
});
```

The response from the server is:

```
{"isOK":false,"message":"Unknown Serial Number!!!"}

Object {isOK: false, message: "Unknown Serial Number!!!"}
VM464:13 false
VM464:14 Unknown Serial Number!!!
```

Since isOK in the server response is false, it should normally trigger to show the alert box, but it's not doing it, instead jumping into the else statement.

Where is my error in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

```
result.isOk
```

is undefined.

```
result.isOK
```

is false.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zvyusn6/)

Comment: that's some sharp eyes you got there :)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli: It comes from years of making similar mistakes :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks David. Need new glasses :D